# Xcode 10 watch kit and watch extension build error

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I have 3 targets, including the main target, WatchKit app and WatchKit extension.
The project doesn't have any build error in Xcode 9.2 but when I build it in Xcode 10 it has these error:

> unable to resolve product type
>   'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp' for platform 'watchos'
>
> unable to resolve product type
>   'com.apple.product-type.watchkit-extension' for platform 'watchos'

I set the "supported platforms" and "base sdk" to watchOS, for both watchapp and extension. but it did not fix this issue.

> also I can mention that my app cannot run in watchOS 5.
>    The developer of this app needs to update it to work with watchOS 5